# Difference find something difficult to do and find something difficult for me to do

Tags: infinitive-clauses

(1). I find it difficult to get a A grade in the cooking exam.
(2). I find it difficult for me to get a A grade in the cooking exam.

I have seen someone write sentences in #2 style somewhere on the Internet, and the sentences confuse me.
Are they both correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I find it difficult (for me) to get *an* A grade in the cooking exam.

It is not incorrect to add "for me", but it is implied in the statement so leaving it out is fine, unless you need it for emphasis (or word count).

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessarily grammatically incorrect but I find the second sentence clumsy. I suspect it's the result of a confusion between the following two sentences:

- I find it difficult to get an A grade in the cooking exam.
- It is difficult for me to get an A grade in the cooking exam.

Comment: I'm not sure what's *wrong* with it, though.